# some confusion on distribution of a random variable- measure theoretic view

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, probability-distributions

[image]

Attached is the lecture notes from several years ago, and I just found something confusing.

**Q1** let there have two measurable spaces $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P}),((0,1),\mathcal{B}_{(0,1)},\mathbb{P}_X)$, the pushforward measure $\mathbb{P}_X$ is defined on borel $\sigma(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow [0,1]$, then why do we borther to have another notation $F_X:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$? **Highlighted in red**

**Q2** Is the law of random variable=distribution of random variable= probability measure $\mathbb{P}_X$

**Q3 proposition 2.1** highlighted in yellow, totally blind with meaning of $X(u)=\inf\{c\in\mathbb{R}|F(c)\geq u\}$, $u$ is the element in sample space, how should I interpret $F(c)\geq u$

Appreciate any comments.

Answer (score 3):

**Q1**

The cumulative distribution function (CDF) $F_X$ is indeed entirely determined by the probability measure $\mathbb P_X$ as $F_X(c) = \mathbb{P}_X(X \in (-\infty,c])$, but they are different objects. May be what confuses you is the fact that $\mathbb{P}_X$ is entirely determined by the values $\mathbb P_X((-\infty,c])$. Every time you encounter a CDF, you could rather work with the underlying probability measure, but this object is easier to manipulate in a lot of contexts.

**Q2**

The law of a random variable is the rule that defines how the outcomes of the random process behaves. Anything that defines uniquely this behaviour can be understood as the law of a random variable. The probability measure is one of them. The cumulative distribution function also works.

**Q3**

This proprosition essentially describes how to generate any law for a real random variable from a uniform r.v.. The notation can be understood as a generalized inverse of $F$. You may have a look for rejection sampling.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 and 2 are correctly answered by Nicomezi.  For Question 3, it is related to the construction of a random variable on the probability measure space $((0,1),{\cal B}((0,1)),\mu_{\text{B}})$ that will admit the cumulative distribution function $F: {\mathbb R} \to [0,1]$.  Here, the random variable is $X:(0,1) \to {\mathbb R}$ that is as defined in the yellow highlighted text.